# Best way to confirm signup with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

What is best way to use Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect to send a SMS to confirm after someone sign up to your Portal developed in Salesforce.

Step1. Some one register on your webpage developed/hosted by salesforce.
Step2. Send a SMS with confirmation code using Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Connect so user can input the code and proceed to step3 after validating the code.
Step3. User login to portal.

I have used this using FuelSDK but dont know if it works with APEX using REST.

Kind Regards

Comment: Would it make more sense to have two questions?... 1) Best way to confirm sign up in Marketing Cloud 2) Working with a REST API from Apex. The second question's for a different audience - Force.com devs, not Marketing Cloud people. As an aside, this doesn't sound like a particularly great use case for Marketing Cloud. It always takes a few minutes to send an SMS and that could be a fairly poor experience for someone expecting an instantaneous SMS to proceed with registration, IMHO.